# Electrostatic and gravitational forces combined

Tags: forces, electrostatics

If we have two bodies of considerable mass and charge both .Will we consider both its gravitational force and electrostatic force to calculate its acceleration ? Why (not) ?

Comment: How would you calculate acceleration?

Comment: @Steeven Obtaining the resultant force and using Newton's law ?

Comment: Indeed, yes. But what exactly does Newton's 2nd law say? It actually doesn't relate acceleration to individual forces, only to the **sum** of all forces. The formula is: $$\sum F=ma \quad \text{or} \quad F_{net}=ma$$ and not merely $$F=ma$$ As the answer below also describes. There is no formula tying an individual force to an acceleration; it is always the total sum that must be used.

Comment: @Steeven Read my comment you will get it .I meant that in the sum do we consider the grav force as when I used it , The answer didnt matched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison which is often made when discussing the forces acting within a nucleus is that for two protons where the ratio of the electrostatic repulsion to the gravitational attraction is found.

$$\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac {q_{\rm p}q_{\rm p}}{r^2} \quad{\Large{:}}\quad G \frac{m_{\rm p}m_{\rm p}}{r^2} \Rightarrow \frac{q_{\rm p}^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 Gm_{\rm p}^2}\quad{\Large{:}}\quad 1 \Rightarrow 10^{36} \quad{\Large{:}}\quad 1$$

So in this context the electrostatic repulsion is obviously much stronger than the gravitational attraction.

You can put your own numbers in to see if you can make the two forces comparable but remember that as you increase the mass you then also have both positive (protons) and negative (electrons) in roughly equal number and thus for large masses the gravitational force of attraction becomes the dominant force as the electrostatic repulsive forces between charges with the same sign tend to cancel out the electrostatic attractive forces between charges with the opposite sign.

Answer (score 1):

The Newton's Second Law of Motion states that:
\begin{align}
   \mathbf{F} \; = \; m \mathbf{a}
\end{align}

- $m$ is the mass of the point particle
- $\mathbf{a}$ is the acceleration of the point particle
- $\mathbf{F}$ is the **net force** acting on the the point particle

Notice the meaning of $\mathbf{F}$ in the formula. It is the net force. That  is summing up all forces acting on the point particle with mass $m$.

Therefore, you have to include both gravitational force and electrostatic force in $\mathbf{F}$ in order to get the correct acceleration $\mathbf{a}$.

Comment: I thought the same and did the same but the answer didnt matched.I think that tha author had ignored value og gravitational force as it was very less as compared to electrostatic force

Comment: @user227271 If one force is very, very tiny compared to another one, then it's influence in the sum is also very, very tiny. So it may be ignored in the equation. Just like you won't include the gravitational attraction from Jupitor  in all your calculations of mechanics here in earth. That might be what the author has done - because the gravitational force is often very small compared to electric forces in practical circumstances. The answer should definitely still be correct, though. Maybe you can provide some more details to the question on what it is that doesn't fit?